# WCF stateful service

Tags: wcf, stateful

Or - at least I think the correct term is stateful. I got a wcf service, listing lots of data back to me. So much data in fact, that I'm exceeding maxrecievedmessagesize - and the program crashes.

I've come to realize that I need to split the calls to the db. Instead of retrieving 5000 rows, I need to get row 1 - 200, remember the id of row number 200, get the next 200 rows from the id of row number 200 and so on.

Does anyone know how to do this? Is stateful (as in 'opposite of stateless') the correct way to go? And how would I proceed...? Could someone point me to an example?

Comment: Service should always be **stateless** if ever possible. Basically, your **caller** should be responsible for specifying which rows he wants - 1-100, 101-200 etc. - the service itself doesn't need to know anything about state. It just returns those rows requested by the client.

Comment: @marc_s you are right that services should better be stateless, on the other hand, passing back the explicit row number to the client exposes much of the internal state of the service and the underlying database..., something which also should be avoided... however, if the whole row (with id) is returned anyway, then you are completely right, so vote up for you

Comment: Let's say I get row 1 - 100, and then 101 - 200, what if someone changes row 58? Wouldn't I prevent this by using state?

And - is this best practice for this sort of problem? (making the caller decide to get row 1 - 100, then 101 - 200)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need stateful service in your scenario. Stateful services is better to avoid, especially when you want to save 5000 rows there.

Client should specified how much data it needs. So it could be method GetRows(index, amount), where index is start index for getting rows and amount of rows to get beginning from starting index.

Also client should ask about data state from service, and service just sends data state. For example when you have these 5000 rows, you could have method on service GetRowsState(index, amount) and the same story it's just saying you the last updated time for your rows, when time you have received is higher or other then on client, then once more to GetRows from server to update client data state.